# Combined 2 Percentage in same cell and using single formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want calculate 17.5% on 1000 and 11.67% on answer of 1000 using one formula and answer should be in single cell. i.e. answer of deduction of 17.5% on 1000 is 825 and 11.67% on 825 is 728. My question is 728 should display rather than 825. I dont want show 825 on my excel sheet. is it possible?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Math problems? You can provide a sample screenshot.

Answer (score 3):

Working back from your example, it *seems* that you want to chain the two reductions. Otherwise there is no way to arrive at 728 (actually, 728.72).
If that is what you mean, then the answer is:

```
=A1*(1-0.175)*(1-0.1167)
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the number is in A1 then just do both calcs together

```
=(A1-(A1*0.175))-((A1-(A1*0.175))*0.1167)
```

Comment: Nicely formulated U are getting +10 ☺

Comment: @RiggsFolly, that is a very lengthy way of expressing Paul's answer.  
Doing the maths...    

(x-(x×a)) - ((x-(x×a))*b  = x×(1-a) - x×(1-a)×b = x×(1-a)×(1-b)

Answer (score 0):

**Caveat:**

*This method will only work with Excel 365 & 2021. I'm suggesting this to use, in anticipation of that the OP is using Recent Version of Excel,,, otherwise will be helpful for the community.*

```
=LET(
    a2_value, A2,
    first_calc, a2_value - (a2_value * 0.175),
    result, first_calc - (first_calc * 0.1167),
    result
)
```

---

1. If you want to make this dynamic then instead of `0.175` & `0.1167`,
   you may use variables.
2. Assume that `0.175` is in cell `A3` and `0.1167` is in `A4`.

*Then you may use this one.*

```
=LET(
    a2_value, A2,
    discount_rate, A3,
    tax_rate, A4,
    first_calc, a2_value - (a2_value * discount_rate),
    result, first_calc - (first_calc * tax_rate),
    result
)
```

---

**N.B.**

1. Where `a2_value` is assigned the value of cell A2, has `1000`.
2. `first_calc`, represents the first intermediate calculation.
3. `result`, stores the final result of the formula.
4. `discount_rate` represents cell `A3` & `tax_rate` to A4.

*Variable Name used with LET are editable.*